# CSS positioning without the use of float or margin adjustments

Tags: css

How can I move my UL element over the the right of the browser without using float, or 'guesstimating' that the element is flush to the right margin through the use of tools such as margin px/% etc?

```
.nav li {
display: inline;
}

.nav h1 {
background-color: red;
display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul {
 display: inline-block;
 border: 1px solid black;
}


 <div class="nav">

        <h1>Resume</h1>
        <ul>
            <li>Home</li>
            <li>Portfolio</li>
            <li>Skills</li>
            <li>Experience</li>
            <li>Contact</li>
        </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Rudi, when I use float, it moves the UL element out of line with the H1 element and looks messy, is there a way around this?

Comment: Yes, either move the ul before the h1, or make the h1 float:left, so they both float. In the latter case, you'll need to clear:both after the elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on what browsers you need to support, you can use flexbox.

[MDN - Flexible Boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Flexible_boxes)

Specifically, you want a container with `display: flex;` and `justify-content: space-between;`

Something like:

```
<div class="nav" style="display: inline-flex; justify-content: space-between;">
  ... child items here ...
</div>
```

Note that flexbox is only supported on IE11+ and all evergreen browsers (Chrome, Firefox, etc).  IE10 has partial support.
[See for more details regarding browser support](http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox).

If you need to support pre-IE10 browsers, you can try using `position: absolute;` and `right: 0;` on your `ul`.

Flexbox:

```
.nav {
  display: inline-flex;  //or just flex
  justify-content: space-between;
} 

.nav li {
  display: inline;
} 

.nav h1 { 
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block; 
} 

.nav ul { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black; 
}
```

Using position:

```
.nav li {
  display: inline;
} 

.nav h1 { 
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block; 
} 

.nav ul { 
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Edited again to better match your example code and because you want justify-content: space-between instead of justify-content: flex-end.  You'd also want inline-flex instead of just flex.

Comment: One last edit with CSS that should just work when copied and pasted.

Comment: Thank you Jim, the last solution is a nice clean, easy solution. Thank you. One thing though, how do I then get the H1 and UL elements to center-align horizontally?

Comment: One way should be to give the nav div a width and then set margin: 0 auto;.  The width will need to be less than the width of the page (in other words, not 100%).

Answer (score 3):

I see from your comment on your original post that you are avoiding floats because your elements are not lining up properly.

```
.nav li {
  display: inline;
}

.nav h1 {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  float: left;
}

.nav ul {
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: right;
}
```

Lines up perfectly when you set the top margins to zero. Your elements are of different height so you need to line them up how you want using margin/padding.

Comment: Thank you Rof, however this aligns the top of each element and it still looks messy, please see here http://jsfiddle.net/mugman/0r4vvj9L/15/  I'd like the UL to align with the middle of the H1 element?

Comment: Also, the element beneath moves up into the white space!

Comment: That's because your .slider div was not set to `display: inline-block;`. Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/0r4vvj9L/28/ but you will have to play with the font size and padding to align it how you would like.

Comment: Alternatively you could also add `clear: both` to `.slider` which would disallow any floating elements on it's left or right and prevent in from sneaking into the whitespace of the above collapsed container (which only contains floats).

Answer (score 0):

Change the following css properties

```
     .nav li {
       display: inline;
     }

     .nav h1 {
       background-color: red;
       display: inline-block;
     }

     .nav ul {
       display: inline-block;
       float:none;
       right:0;
       margin-right:10px; // its just an example you can move as much as you want
       border: 1px solid black;
     }
```

```
    <h1>Resume</h1>
    <ul>
        <li>Home</li>
        <li>Portfolio</li>
        <li>Skills</li>
        <li>Experience</li>
        <li>Contact</li>
    </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try position: absolute;, right: 0px;